# Use jquery to just set radio buttons that are currently a certain value

Tags: jquery

I've an HTML page with a number of tables, one for each user in the database.
The first four columns of each table are radio buttons, with the values: G, A, X and blank respectively.

What I want to do is set the radio button to e.g. 'A' for all rows that are currently blank.

Here was where I started:

```
var st='A';
$('#user123 input').val([st]);
```

This works, but it also sets to A the rows that were already 'G' or 'X'.

Here is what I've tried that didn't work:

```
$('#user123 input[value=]').siblings().val([st]);
```

(nothing gets set)

```
$('#user123 input[value=]').parent().children().val([st]);
```

(the blank radio button gets cleared, none get set)

```
$('#user123 input[value=]').val([st]);
```

(the blank radio button gets cleared, none get set)

```
$('#user123 input').not('[value=G]').val([st]);
```

(planning to add exceptions for A and X later, but it already doesn't work - all radio buttons get set to 'A', not just the blank ones)

I'm really close aren't I? But I just cannot find the magic incantation I need!

Here is a cut-down version of the table HTML:

```
<table id="user123">
<tr>
<td><input name="r520" value="G" type="radio"></td>
<td><input name="r520" value="A" type="radio"></td>
<td><input name="r520" value="X" type="radio"></td>
<td><input name="r520" value="" type="radio" checked></td>
<td>2011-06-01</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="r767" value="G" type="radio"></td>
<td><input name="r767" value="A" type="radio"></td>
<td><input name="r767" value="X" type="radio"></td>
<td><input name="r767" value="" type="radio" checked></td>
<td>2011-06-03</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks for replies; here is the solution I went with (mainly inspired by michelpm's):

```
var st='A';
$('#user123 tr').each(function() {
    if($("input:radio[value=]:checked",this).length){
        $("input:radio[value="+st+"]",this).attr("checked",true);  
        }
    });
```

Comment: Someone asked "Why?" The context is that an ajax call has modified multiple DB rows on the back-end, so I'm updating the UI to be in sync. If the changes had been more complex I'd have done an ajax get() call to simply fetch fresh data; but too many ajax calls like that can make a web site horribly slow when it gets busy. My solution saves (in order of importance) one back-end SQL request, one http request and at least a couple of TCP/IP packets :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by blank you meant no radio is checked in that row:

http://jsfiddle.net/michelpm/GzPrd/

```
$("#user123 tr").each(function() {
    if($(":radio:checked", this).length == 0) {
        $(":radio[value=A]", this).attr("checked", true);        
    }
});
```

**EDIT**:

If you want so bad to do that in one line this one may do the trick...

http://jsfiddle.net/michelpm/GzPrd/2/

```
function select(value) {
     return function() {
        $(":radio[name=" + this.name + "][value=" + value + "]")
            .attr("checked", true);
    }; 
}

$("#user123 :radio:not([value]):checked").each(select('A'));
```

Comment: I think by blank he means that the radio button with an empty value is checked. Hence the checked attribute in the supplied HTML.

Comment: I don't know what he is trying to achieve with this code, but if he is trying to enforce a non empty value to be selected, perhaps that empty radio wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @michelpm As Chris said it was the empty string radio button that was the search key; but your example was easy to adapt for that; in fact, for really robust code, I should handle the none-checked case as well.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you are going to use this code on multiple tables/rows on multiple users, you should probably make it a bit more dynamic by adding a class to the table. Consider the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var value_to_check = 'A';

    $('.user-table tr').each(function() {

        //is blank checked?
        if( $(this).find( 'input[value=]' ).is(':checked') )
            $(this).find( 'input[value=' + value_to_check + ']' ).attr( 'checked', 'checked' );

    });

});
```

This code assumes that the table has the class "user-table" instead of just an ID such as "#user123". It then iterates through each row, since your example HTML shows the need for more than 1 row. It then checks each row to see if the radio button with the "" value is checked. If so, then it checks the row you have predefined, which in this case is "A".

Comment: Thanks for the idea; so you think there is no snappy jquery one-liner for this case? BTW, #user123 is what is desired (I have 10+ tables on the page, and only want to update the one for user 123); the actual code is much more dynamic, but I simplified it to save having lots of distracting variables to explain.

Comment: Gotcha. There is no simple, one line code that can pull this off to my knowledge. You have to check for the checked "empty" value, and then set the correct value. If you only had 2 radio buttons, it might be as easy as one-line.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question, but I think you want to do this:

If a blank row is checked, change it to make the A the checked item.  If that is right, you could do this.

```
if($('#user123 tr input[value=""]')){
    $('#user123 tr input[value=A]').attr("checked", true); 
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/vbyS6/

Also, you wrote

> so you think there is no snappy jquery one-liner for this case?

You could smush this into one line:

```
if($('#user123 tr input[value=""]')){$('#user123 tr input[value=A]').attr("checked", true);}
```

Comment: Nice idea, but the problem with this is similar to a couple of my attempts - if any of the rows have a value="" radio button (the first line of your example), then change _all_ rows to be value="A" (the second line); I want to just change the rows that currently have value=""